# One automation tool for Functional, UI, Database and WebServices

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework

I know this could be opinion based question but still as per current trend in Software Industry which tool is most suitable if it is an e-Commerce based project (website).

**In this project there will be:**

1. Functionality testing, Unit Testing, Regression
2. UI testing
3. Database testing
4. WebServices testing

All above would taken care by an automation team.

**Tool's feature:**

1. It should be open-source
2. Quick framework setup e.g. most of the things are part of OOTB feature. E.g. setup(), teardown(), assertions etc.
3. It can be integrated with test management tool like TestNg, Mocha, Grunt etc
4. It can be integrated with Jenkins, SauceLabs etc

Anyone who has solved such requirement from client. If not please put some tool's name forward.

Comment: It will be difficult to give "one" tool, python unittest framework + selenium may help you out

Comment: An open source windows UI test automation tool is tough to find even on it's own, is it not?  Web Services and Web UI is easier to find...

Comment: Testng is not a test management tool. It serves for running automated tests.

Comment: Quite broad range to be covered. Create your own framework :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)?

1. UI Testing:

   - [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) - using real browsers
   - [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) - on HTTP(S) protocol level
2. Database Testing - [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
3. Web Services Testing - [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)
4. It is free and open source
5. Has [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group), [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) and [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions) out of the box
6. None of these are test management tools
7. Being a pure Java application JMeter can be integrated where Java can be integrated, i.e. [there are several ways for launching it in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) and even the [performance plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) to visualize the results
8. JMeter is designed for load testing so you will be able to turn your functional tests into load tests in few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are separate tools for each of the pieces you need.

The only open-source tool I know that has them combined  is TestLink

A frequent commercial solution is HP Quality Center

Comment: You mean http://testlink.org/, but this is test management tool, I mean to write manual test cases and manage them.It doesn't automate any of above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but I do not think there’s one tool for all of your requirements. However, Ranorex supports [automated functional testing](http://www.ranorex.com/automated-functional-testing.html), [regression testing](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/automated-regression-testing-with-ranorex/) and UI test automation. It is a commercial tool but in my opinion it pays off because the support is really good.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you would need is a framework that will support this testing.  Take a look at BDDfire, which is a framework that can incorporate a lot of what you are asking for.  https://github.com/Shashikant86/bddfire

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to knit together multiple tools to cover all of the testing types from one "interface", you could look at cucumber.  I have not used it extensively, but I do know that it integrates with both Selenium and Watir, and I believe SoapUI/TestNG.  If you are looking to integrate with windows application testing, we would have to do some research...  (I will get there sooner or later, being in that sphere of testing at this time..)

The caveat of course is that the test case format is both a blessing and a curse.  It's designed to be something where EVERYONE from product management, to development to Quality assurance to users can look at the test case and know what it means and discuss it on even footing.  If you get everyone to the table, the verboseness and extra level of abstraction pays off.  If you are writing Gerkin for yourself as a QA, it's an extra level of stuff to design before you get to writing test automation.  But if you do it right, derived test cases do become easy to write/implement.

There are java, ruby (the original) and visual studio flavors as well.